# R converting "Character" column into "Date" format

Tags: r, date-format, date-formatting

please do not smash me before reading. First of all before asking the question I spent 3 hours just try to figure out couple of things, I have tried different approaches however it does not work, if you are here to direct me go google it, please do not. Thanks.

I had an xls data frame, tried to read in R with my lecturer told, it does not work, he basically wants us to implement a rjava library to read .xls file with read_xlsx(), i tried, nope does not work, just can not read even the file.
(As usual for me, read_csv() format, I converted .xls into .csv and finally could read in my R script.
And hurraa worked!!!)

Here is the tricky problem, I am explaining all steps, want you to feel my pain.
These are my column names:

When i split into 2 columns and try to convert, function works but all data under the column of date or time or date...time disappears, all i see is NA all the way down.

I appriciate if you can help me, thanks a lot.

`sapply(myDataFrame, class)`

Date...Timestamp              DO1              DO2   Controlling.DO               pH
"character"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"
Biomass    Titre..mg.mL.      Base.Buffer      Media.Batch
"numeric"        "numeric"        "integer"        "integer"**

As you can see I got a very very well thought column name (Date...Timestamp), anyway I need to convert char format into Date format, but all column all the way down "28/03/2020 17:28" formatted.

What i did ?

```
#Split Date / Timestamp column by character

myDataFrame <- myDataFrame %>%
                mutate(Date = str_sub(Date...Timestamp, 1,11)) %>%
                mutate(Time = str_sub(Date...Timestamp, 11))

#DataFrame manipulation, drop the old Data Timestamp column
myDataFrame <- myDataFrame %>%
                select(-Date...Timestamp)
```

splitted column into two as wanted, date and time, cool!!! but when I try to change type of columns I get different variations of errors with each function.

i tried  as.Date(), as.date.numeric(), as.POSIXct()

```
# converting to datetime object
myDataFrame[["Date"]] <- as.POSIXct(myDataFrame[["Date"]], format = "%D/%M/%Y")
myDataFrame[["Time"]] <- as.POSIXct(myDataFrame[["Time"]], format = "%H:%M")

myDataFrame$Date <- as.Date(myDataFrame$Date)
myDataFrame$Time <- as.Date(myDataFrame$Time)

# tried before splitting and splitting afterwards, still error.
myDataFrame$Date...Timestamp <- as.Date(myDataFrame$Date...Timestamp)
```

Comment: Hi CRM. Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's honestly no need to be defensive about asking a question. The folks here are happy to help, particularly when you show that you have tried hard to fix the problem yourself. The thing is that in base R, there is no native time format without a date, so you need to convert your strings to a date time format (that's what POSIXct is).  Have you tried `as.POSIXct(myDataFrame$Date...Timestamp, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')`? If necessary you can convert the output using `as.Date` on it.

Comment: `read_csv()` has a `col_types` argument, you might import everything as character then you can inspect the object, this will allow you to show more. I feel your pain but you'll have better answers if you trim down your answer to what's relevant, removing the intro and ref to rjava etc since it seems not relevant if I understand correctly.

Comment: @moodymudskipper, I am the victim of my masters program lecturer, he gave a file format of 97-03 dated, I need to do report of dataframe with related questions. Thanks for your approach, rjava was not my suggestion was an  instruction, sometimes they want you to do something exactly how they did it.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks for approach, I did it exactly written, result is all data frame turned into just : 2020-03-28 17:28:00 GMT" "2020-03-31 14:03:00 BST" "2020-03-31 14:04:00 BST" there is any another data in the table.